# update ngx-admin from 2.3.0 to 3.0.0

Tags: node.js, angular6, ngx-admin

I'm currently using [ngx-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin) which is on version 2.3.0 and now it is updated to 3.0.0 [see here](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). I just want to know how to update it without affecting my entire project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your tags, I presume your app is running on `Angular 6` where as if you read the `CHANGELOG.md` link which you've mentioned in your post, it clearly states that,

**Angular 7+ now required**.

```
The following libraries were updated:
@agm/core
@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
@swimlane/ngx-charts
ng2-ckeditor
ngx-echarts
```

Hence I'm afraid you will have to upgrade your project to `Angular 7` in order to execute it seamlessly.